Login page isn't redirecting - Django
I'm trying to create a basic authentication page with user and password, and it is almost working, almost.
I found that the authentication process is working but the app is failing at redirecting to the home page.
Here's the code
From Views
def home(request):
    print(request.user)
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return render(request, "home/home.html")
    else:
        return redirect("login/")

def login(request):
    error = ''
    if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        try:
            user = AppUser.objects.get(email=username)
        except AppUser.DoesNotExist:
            error = 'Usuario no encontrado'
            return render(request, 'login.html', {'error': error, 'form': Login()})
        if hasattr(user, 'appuserauth'):
            if user.appuserauth.check_password(password):
                uauth = authenticate(request, username=user.email, password=password)
                if uauth is not None:
                    login(request, uauth)
                    return redirect("home")
            else:
                error = 'Contraseña incorrecta'
                return render(request, 'login.html', {'error': error, 'form': Login()})
        else:
            error = 'El usuario no tiene una contraseña'
            return render(request, 'login.html', {'error': error, 'form': Login()})
    else:
        return render(request, "login.html", {
            "form": Login(),
            "error": error
        })


From urls
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('home/', views.home, name='home'),
    path('inventario/', views.inventario, name='inventario'),
    path('compras/', views.compras, name='compras'),
    path('ventas/', views.ventas, name='ventas'),
    path('login/', views.login, name='login'),
]

Does someone know what I'm doing wrong?
enter image description here
Thanks
I've tried changing from redirect to render, and I also tried to track the redirection.
I'm expecting that after login, the app redirects to home page

you should return redirect in post method, but you return render

**Views:**
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login as auth_login
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .models import AppUser  # Ensure this points to your custom user model

def home(request):
    print(request.user)
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return render(request, "home/home.html")
    else:
        return redirect("login")

def login(request):
    error = ''
    if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        try:
            user = AppUser.objects.get(email=username)
        except AppUser.DoesNotExist:
            error = 'Usuario no encontrado'
            return render(request, 'login.html', {'error': error, 'form': Login()})
        
        if hasattr(user, 'appuserauth'):
            if user.appuserauth.check_password(password):
                uauth = authenticate(request, username=user.email, password=password)
                if uauth is not None:
                    auth_login(request, uauth)  # Use auth_login to avoid confusion
                    return redirect("home")
            else:
                error = 'Contraseña incorrecta'
        else:
            error = 'El usuario no tiene una contraseña'
        
        return render(request, 'login.html', {'error': error, 'form': Login()})
    
    return render(request, "login.html", {"form": Login(), "error": error})

URLs:
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
   path('home/', views.home, name='home'),
   path('login/', views.login, name='login'),

 ]
**Key Changes:**

auth_login: I renamed the import for login() from Django to auth_login to avoid conflict with your view function name.
authenticate(): Ensured that username=user.email is passed if email is being used as the username for authentication.
Redirect Fix: After successful authentication, the redirect should correctly point to home, which matches the home path in your URLs.


Thanks, I didn't notice that the Django login and my function were named the same

I am agree with another answer about necessary on using redirect instead of render.
Your code should looks like that:
# views.py

return redirect(
    'dashboard:income_month',
    year=year, # if you have any additional arguments in path
    month=month
    )

And also you can set up redirect for some actions in settings.py. For example redirection after registration, log in, log out and other standard authentication actions.
It will be looks like that:
# settings.py

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'pages:homepage'

LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = 'pages:homepage'

Here (Django Documentation) you can find more information about using standard redirect constants. It may be very useful.

just go through these steps:
step-1: define app_name in urls.py.
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = "your_app_name"

urlpatterns = [
    path('home/', views.home, name='home'),
    path('inventario/', views.inventario, name='inventario'),
    path('compras/', views.compras, name='compras'),
    path('ventas/', views.ventas, name='ventas'),
    path('login/', views.login, name='login'),
]

step-2: write redirect like this.
return redirect("your_app_name:home")

I hope this fixes your problem, and may i know if there any issue after going through these steps.

Thank you.
In the end, I decided to change the User management to the framework's default tool. I'm still reading the documentation, I didn't know that I can set an app name too, only knew it for the urls.
